# how to understand this sentence(reading comprehension)

Tags: reading-comprehension

> ここで、「叱る」うえでの注意点を一つ。叱ることが何度も続くと、叱られることに対する慣れが生じ、「いつものことか」と子どもが感じとり、指導者の本当にいいたいことが伝わらないということがあります。叱ることによって、得られる効果が半減しないためにも、**指導者は日頃から注意深く、また意思を持って、みずからと向き合う必要があるのです**

I can't understand "また意思を持って、みずからと向き合う" ,what does the bold sentence mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are cutting the sentence in a wrong place. The base is

- 指導者は日頃からみずからと向き合う必要があるのです

and

- 注意深く、また意思を持って

describes ***how** teachers should reflect on themselves*.

[また](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F/#je-71622) here means *and*.

I think the passage is rather vague, but it literally says *Teachers always need to reflect on themselves, carefully and intentionally/willingly*.

Comment: does this bold sentence have any relationship with the context above?I can't see any relationship beween them.the context above say  指導者 should use 叱る as a educational method in a careful way,then the paragraph say 指導者 should reflect on themself,what is the point?

Comment: @CN.hitori That's what I said vague. But I suppose the author is suggesting that reflecting on oneself contributes to scolding pupils in a considerate manner instead of doing so routinely (which would lose effect on pupils).